# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier that I cannot figure out for EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have been stuck for a few days on this and it is so simple. One of you wizards can help me out.

Problem:

I installed Express, EJS and my landing.ejs won't load with the correct HTML partials. It gives me the following errors.

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YHtQ.png)

What I have done:

I have installed EJS, Express. My syntax for the route should be alright. My header and footer is good too. I have the same path and syntax in another project and my file loads just fine. What is wrong here!?!

[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STtFW.png)

[landing.ejs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wL0E.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your express app dont know where the partials folder is ....

You have to add a line of code

```
// view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Comment: This didn't work and I don't quite know why we need it? I have another app in which my code works fine without the path.join. Is there a reason why I need it for this app?

Comment: Ok then , you have some where in your ejs file a syntax error , propably you have miss a char like  '<,>,%' or you have a syntax error at your embed javascript function ,check all you javascript functions perhaps you miss a curly brace.